# install redis as windows service

Tags: windows-services, redis

I've just installed redis on windows with [**MSOpenTech port**](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis). Everything is fine but the windows service. In order to run cmd, I need to create Redis command line arguments which I don't know how to achieve.

How can I solve this problem?

This is the instruction:

> Running Redis as a Service
>
> In order to better integrate with the Windows Services model, new
>   command line arguments have been introduced to Redis. These service
>   arguments require an elevated user context in order to connect to the
>   service control manager. If these commands are invoked from a
>   non-elevated context, Redis will attempt to create an elevated context
>   in which to execute these commands. This will cause a User Account
>   Control dialog to be displayed by Windows and may require
>   Administrative user credentials in order to proceed.
>
> Installing the Service
>
> ```
> --service-install
> ```
>
> This must be the first argument on the redis-server command line.
>   Arguments after this are passed in the order they occur to Redis when
>   the service is launched. The service will be configured as Autostart
>   and will be launched as "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService". Upon successful
>   installation a success message will be displayed and Redis will exit.
>
> This command does not start the service.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose
> ```
>
> Uninstalling the Service
>
> ```
> --service-uninstall
> ```

Answer (score 34):

In dir where you installed redis instead of

```
redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf--loglevel verbose
```

do

```
redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose
```

(i.e. Add a space before "--loglevel")

Comment: I ran the command. It says Redis installed successfully as a service but I am not able to start the service. Any pointers?

Comment: Same here, it says the service started and then stopped because nothing was using it

Comment: I had to look this over a few times before realizing there's a space between `redis.windows.conf` and `--log-level`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to starting redis from command line, before installing the service you will need to specify the **maxheap** parameter. Open the redis.windows.conf file and find the line which comments out maxheap; specify a suitable size in bytes.

Then run 
`redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose`

You will need to manually start the service after you install it or just restart windows.

Comment: I had a problem that after installing the service would auto start and then stop directly. Setting the maxheap as suggested above fixed this problem!

Comment: FYI, MaxHeap isn't needed anymore in Redis 3.x

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is,

run command prompt as an administrator and than open redis directory and write

redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose

the service will successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

For me as mentioned here, [Redis doesn't start as windows service on Windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478628/redis-doesnt-start-as-windows-service-on-windows7)
by installing the service with --service-name parameter runs the service magically without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The *Microsoft Redis Open Tech* project has been abandoned and no longer supported.
Memurai is a Windows port of Redis that derives from that Open Tech project (see [here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3)).
 It is actively maintained and supported.
Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below document and follow the steps,

1. download Redis latest version .msi from [here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases)
2. Follow the instruction mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@mayank_goyal/how-to-install-redis-and-as-a-windows-service-f0ab2559a3b)