# Redis doesn't start as windows service on Windows7

Tags: redis, windows-7, windows-services, nosql

I used this build to install redis on my windows7:

https://github.com/rgl/redis (git)

http://ruilopes.com/redis-setup/binaries/redis-2.4.6-setup-64-bit.exe (binary)

Service has been installed sucessfully, but it doesn't start:

[image: redis service doesn't start]

The message says: 'Redis Server service on local computer was started and then stopped'. logs folder is empty. redis-server.exe starts properly without service. How can I fix this? Propose any other working dist. plz if you know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue on Windows 10 when trying to start Redis v3.0.503 as a service.

I had to install the service with a service-name param and it magically started working.

`C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose --service-name redisService`

[7484] 04 Feb 00:03:53.610 # Granting read/write access to 'NT AUTHORITY\Network Service' on: "C:\redis" "C:\redis" [7484] 04 Feb 00:03:53.612 # Redis successfully installed as a service.

Found the solution here:
[Redis-windows GitHub Wiki - Issues might happen](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows/wiki/Issues-might-happen)

Answer (score 2):

Commonly the Redis server on windows fails to start if you don't specify a **maxheap** parameter, before installing the service try to edit the **redis.windows.conf** file and uncomment maxheap parameter to something suitable.